# Add widgets on the fly in pyside

Tags: python, widget, pyside, qscrollarea

Very new to pyside so maybe a stupid question. I want to create a pyside UI which has a variable number of items in it and also has the possibility to add items while it is running and to make it even more complex it also needs a scroll bar to fit it all on screen!

This is what I've got right now:

```
import sys

from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore 
class example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(example, self).__init__()

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget()

        self.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)

        for i in range(5):
            btn = QtGui.QPushButton("test"+str(i))
            self.layout.addWidget(btn,i,0)
            btn.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        self.count = i
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)


        self.scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

        grid.addWidget(self.scroll,3,0)
        self.setLayout(grid)


    def buttonClicked(self):
        title = QtGui.QLabel('Title'+str(self.count))
        self.layout.addWidget(title,self.count + 1,0)
        self.count += 1
        self.widget.addLayout(self.layout,0)
        self.scroll.addWidget(self.widget,0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    dialog = example()
    dialog.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But somehow the layout gets messed up when adding items through one of the buttons.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Thanx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not far off. The key piece you're missing is [QScrollArea.setWidgetResizable](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop), which will ensure the scrollarea automatically resizes its viewport to fit the contents.

I've made some other adjustments to your example and added comments where appropriate:

```
class example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(example, self).__init__()

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget()

        # set the widget as parent of its own layout
        self.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.widget)

        for i in range(5):
            btn = QtGui.QPushButton("test"+str(i))
            self.layout.addWidget(btn,i,0)
            btn.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

        # following lines are redundant
        # self.count = i
        # self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        # need this so that scrollarea handles resizing
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        # these two lines may not be needed now
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

        grid.addWidget(self.scroll, 3, 0)
        self.setLayout(grid)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        title = QtGui.QLabel('Title' + str(self.layout.count()))
        self.layout.addWidget(title)
        # following lines are redundant
        # self.layout.addWidget(title, self.count + 1, 0)
        # self.count += 1
        # self.widget.addLayout(self.layout,0)
        # self.scroll.addWidget(self.widget,0)
```